# Adding two rows in an augmented matrix: does this always preserve the set of solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a system of linear equations, we construct an augmented matrix, and may modify it using the three elementary row operations:

- Interchange two rows.
- Multiply a row by a non-zero constant.
- Add a row to another row.

These correspond to operations on the system of equations.  It's fairly clear that the first two operations preserve the set of solutions.  It is also clear that any solution to the original system of equations will also satisfy to the modified system of equations.

*Question*:  How do we know that any solution to the modified system of equations also satisfies the original system of equations?

Comment: Let (X,Y) be a solution to the system ax+by = c and dx + ey = f. This means that aX+bY=c as well as dX+eY=f are true statements. Let's perform an addition. We get (a+d)x+(b+e)y=c+f Now (X,Y) is a solution of this system as well, because by plugging in we get (a+d)X+(b+e)Y-c-f=0. Work out the brackets and use the true statements of the beginning to get another true statement. Maybe not a very formal proof, but hopefully intuitively enough

Comment: I'm mostly asking about "going back" from the modified equations to the original ones (and, particularly in the case of adding two rows).  I can see why if $(X,Y)$ is a solution to the original equations, then $(X,Y)$ is a solution to the modified equations.  But, how do we know that if $(X,Y)$ is a solution to the modified equations then $(X,Y)$ is a solution to the original equations?  Might we have introduced additional solutions?

Comment: I would agree with Boris' approach here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every of these three operations has the inverse, which has the same form. So apply the inverses to the modified system and use your reasonings. E.g., you know that multipling a row by $a\ne 0$ preserves the set of solutions. So multiply the row of the modified system by $a^{-1}\ne 0$. Then you get the original system, and the set of solutions is preserved.